# Extjs spring 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs

i am developing demo project on Extjs and spring mvc .in that user will enter some details and result page will display the user details.but when i use action:'/HelloWeb/addStudent.htm',to send request it gives me 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
and when i use url: '/HelloWeb/addStudent.htm'then it gives 404 the requested resource not available

how to solve this problem

This is my index.jsp having extjs code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function(){
            Ext.QuickTips.init();
     var login = new Ext.FormPanel({ 
items:[{ 
            fieldLabel:'Name', 
            name:'Name', 
            allowBlank:false 
        },{ 
            fieldLabel:'age', 
            name:'age', 
            allowBlank:false 
        },{ 
            fieldLabel:'id', 
            name:'id', 
            allowBlank:false 
        }],


    buttons:[{ 
            text:'Submit',
            formBind: true,  

            handler:function(){ 
                login.getForm().submit({ 

                //url: '/HelloWeb/addStudent.htm' ,
                  action:'/HelloWeb/addStudent.htm',
                  method:'POST',
                  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                }); 

            }  
        }] 
    });
```

This is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)

 public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
  ModelMap model) {
  model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
  model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
  model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

  return "result";
```

}

This my Servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="nil" />
```

This my web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mapping all `*.htm` requests to Spring, but the request mapping in your controller is set to `/addStudent` - without the `.htm` suffix

Try adding the `.htm`to the mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: thanks for u r rpl but I have tried that aslo  @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST) but still it not working

Answer (score 0):

The form action is :

```
action:'/HelloWeb/addStudent.htm'
```

which is posting the request to `/addStudent.htm`. But the `addStudent` method is mapped to `/addStudent`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

To make it work, change the value of `value` parameter of `@RequestMapping` annotation  to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
  ModelMap model) {
...
}
```